# jquery: Maintaining the same button size given changes in the text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize() {
    $('#btnPoint').css('width', $('#btnPoint').width());
}
```

When I debug it in Chrome `$('#btnPoint').width()` is 83 before the width is set. But it becomes 67 immediately after the `css` statement is executed.

What is going on?

**EDIT**

I have no particular stylesheets loaded. Here is my html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=bla-bla-bla&sensor=false&libraries=geometry">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sdr.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div style="display: table; height: 100%; width: 100%;">
        <div id="data" style="display: table-row; height: 20px;">
            <div style="display: table-cell;">
                <input id="btnPoint" type="button" value="Mark the point" onclick="markPoint()" />
                Point: <input id="txtPoint" type="text" /><br />
                <input id="btnPolygon" type="button" value="Mark the polygon" />
                Polygon:<input id="txtPolygon" type="text" />
             </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-row; ">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="display: table-cell;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The example you provided has nothing to do with changing the text.

Comment: Try ` $('#btnPoint').width($('#btnPoint').width());`

Comment: what does your CSS look like?

Comment: We need to see the html associated with the button. See jQuery docs. http://api.jquery.com/width/ and http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/

Comment: it's interesting. it does seem to [shrink the button here](http://jsfiddle.net/fskreuz/pnCBc/)

Comment: Worth noting that if you change the text and use .width() in the same statement to set the width that it should come last or the width will not work: `$('#btnPoint').width($('#btnPoint').outerWidth()).text('p');` works
 vs `$('#btnPoint').text('p').width($('#btnPoint').outerWidth()); `does not set the width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's [`width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) doesn't contain padding or border which are default styles on a `button` use [`outerWidth()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) like:

```
$('#btnPoint').css('width', $('#btnPoint').outerWidth());
```

to keep your button the same size, but have the text morph to fit, check out the [fitText plugin](http://fittextjs.com/) or [fitText on github](https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js) it's made for large display text, but might work for your needs.

Comment: I have to admit, this is strange.